# How to install rclone mount on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, mount, sync, cloud

I followed the instructions mentioned on the main [site](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/) by opening the CMD and typing this command line,

```
C:\Users\***\OneDrive\Desktop\rclone-v1.51.0-windows-amd64>rclone mount gdrive: E:
```

where `gdrive` is the name of the remote and `E:` is my local drive.
After the execution an error message popped up which reads,

```
Cannot create WinFsp-FUSE file system: mount point in use.
2020/04/15 18:31:29 ERROR : Google drive root '': Mount failed
2020/04/15 18:31:29 Fatal error: failed to mount FUSE fs: mount stopped before calling Init: mount failed
```

Acknowledging that I have installed the *winfps-1.6* on my local system drive `C:` and that's all what I have done so far. As a non-programmer I would like to know what I have messed up in this procedure and how to get rclone to mount?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, at first I didn't notice my mistake in specifying the *destination* path where I should locate the mounted folder. In easy words, the mounting point or the `destination` in the syntax

```
mount sourceFile destinationFile
```

*should* always contain at least one folder after a specified local drive. For instance, the command,

```
rclone mount gdrive: E:/Newfolder
```

allows to mount the hole google drive `gdrive` to a folder `NewFolder` located in the local drive `E:` without any errors,

```
The service rclone has been started.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had created an empty folder for my mount, but this was wrong; rclone will create the folder on its own.